# All about Domains & DNS

Tags: networking, dns, laravel-5, fortrabbit

I bought a Tld from godaddy

I linked my tld to my App URL by method (redirect with masking)

It is no problem with Redirection but in the address bar is displayed my App url and not the tld

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how Godaddy implements "domain masking". I guess your site get's loaded in an iframe then. That's most likely not what you want (quirky + bad SEO). Instead of forwarding you can point the domain to the App with a CNAME record to your Apps name. Please see the Goddady help how to do that. On fortrabbit the "custom domain" must be registered with the service to receive requests.